# How to disable the remaining index pages of gridview except the current index page duing pagination?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, pagertemplate

I have a gridview and there is a column of buttons in it. when i click the "book" button
the current page index(pagination- 1 2 3 4) should be enabled and the remaining page indexes(pagination- 1 2 3 4) should be disabled. and at the same time when i hit the "cancel" button all the page indexes(pagination- 1 2 3 4) should be enable back to normal. How can i achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to enable/disable paging itself?